# Error "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-data-by-id 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

Good Evening, I am new to Laravel and trying one app for inhouse site.
Trying to Pass variable (BuffaloID) from View to Controller and get data from database for that Specific id and return to View showing modal with data for that Specific ID.
While doing the same i am getting error " "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-data-by-id 404 (Not Found)"
Can anyone help me on the same...Thanks in Advance

web.php File

```
Route::post('get-data-by-id/{buffaloid}',[BuffaloMonitorController::class,'getbuffaloidformonitor'])->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');
('getbuffaloidformonitor');
```

BuffalomonitorController File

```
     public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $req )
        {

            
            $inspectionbuffaloid = ($buffaloid);
            

            $viewinspectiondata = buffalomonitor::where ('buffaloID','=','$inspectionbuffaloid')->get(); // get data for view inspection data for selected buffaloID

            
            return view ('pages.Buffalo.BuffaloMonitor',['viewinspectiondata'=>$viewinspectiondata]);

            
        }
            
            
            
        }
```

BuffaloMonitor.blade.php

```
                   <script>

                $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
                }); 

        // get data from table and show in View modal by Buffalo ID.


                $(document).on('click', '.viewmonitormodal', function() {

                    var modal_data = $(this).data('info').split(',');
                    
                    $('#viewbuffaloID').val(modal_data[1]);

                    var buffaloid = document.getElementById('viewbuffaloID').value // get buffalo id from textbox to get data for that ID
                    var token = "{{ csrf_token()}}";

                    alert(buffaloid);

                    $.ajax({
                        type                :'POST',
                        url                 :"{{ url('get-data-by-id') }}",
                        //dataType          : 'json',
                        data                :{buffalo_id:buffaloid, _token: token},

                        success:function(refbuffaloid){

                            alert(buffaloid);
                        
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Route**
try reviewing the docs because your Route should be

```php
// and import the BuffaloController on the top like
// use App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController

Route::get('get-data-by-id/{id}',[BuffaloMonitorController::class, 'getbuffaloidformonitor')->name('getbuffaloidformonitor'); // remove anything after this
```

**The Controller**
should know that you will be passing it an id so enter it as a paramet

```php
public function getbuffaloidformonitor($BuffaloId, $Request $req)
        {
            return $BuffaloId;
        }
```

As a common practice if you're passing an ID to the route you should make it a get request, and send the request like `url(.... "get-data-by-id" . $buffaloID)`.

```js
                  $.ajax({
                        type                :'GET',
                        url                 :"{{ url('get-data-by-id') }}" + buffaloid // not sure about this routing but just add the buffaloid to the url
                        success:function(refbuffaloid){

                            alert(buffaloid);
                        
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.... Its work but have one error - POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-data-by-id 500 (Internal Server Error)                    and if i disable  - return $BuffaloId; from controller there will be no error.... Did i miss anything....

Comment: Yes in the route did you add the `]` that i missed when pointing to the controller

Comment: Yes... Added the "]" in route... Thanks........ now one more point -  public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $req, $buffaloid=null) - if i remove "null" then error was 500 and in log file - local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function

Comment: Yes because if you want to remove the default value of `$BuffaloID` you should configure the route to accept a dynamic ID like `Route::post('get-data-by-id/{TheID}', [BuffaloMonitorController::class])`

Comment: HI.. Good Evening.... Sorry for Delay Reply.... I am  Stuck at same Error.....Anyone one help me out.......

Comment: Please update the question with your current problem

Comment: And let me know

Comment: @RahulW no problem, i updated the answer please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your Route is requiring a parameter that you need to pass to the controller, but the controller isn't aware of the parameter. You need to pass it to the controller method as a parameter.

Route:

```
Route::post('get-data-by-id/{buffaloid}',[BuffaloMonitorController::class,'getbuffaloidformonitor'])->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');
```

Controller (cleaned up a bit}:

```
public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $request, string $buffaloid )
{
    $viewinspectiondata = buffalomonitor::where('buffaloID', (int)$buffaloid)->get();

    return view ('pages.Buffalo.BuffaloMonitor' ['viewinspectiondata'=>$viewinspectiondata]);
    
}
```

Comment: Hello.....Sorry for Delay Reply...... I totally lost in this.......... Getting Error                          
"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-data-by-id?buffaloid=Buffalo-01 404 (Not Found)" but when i replace ? with / then link is work..... Can you help me where did i making the mistake.... Sorry for delay and Thanks in Advance